# According to Shia Islam what is the law regarding when we can invade and conquer another country?

Tags: shiism, jihad

Under what circumstances could for example Persia be justified in engaging in a preemptive strike on for example Rome? Does there have to be evidence that Rome presents a danger to Persia? Or is it enough that Rome is known not only to be the home of idol worship but also the leader of idol worship worldwide?